# How to unit test SKStoreReviewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, storekit

Since SKStoreReviewController doesn't have any delegates (or much documentation), I'm stumped on how to unit test it. This could be a dumb question, but googling "unit test SKStoreReviewController" doesn't yield much. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what would you unit test in SKStoreReviewController???

Comment: @IvanIčin, Sure, I've got some logic that dictates when the SKStoreReviewController is presented. I'd like to test that the SKStoreReviewController is, indeed, shown when expected. Something like ```SKStoreReviewController.viewDidAppear()``` would be helpful, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: You can unit test that logic. SKStoreReviewController is not granted to appear always anyway (though in debug currently it does but that logic may change at any time).

Comment: And you're saying that testing everything around SKStoreReviewController (but not it itself) is the best practice for testing it? I'm only asking because I wouldn't test something like an API like that. I'd want to mock it, etc.

Comment: As said SKStoreReviewController is randomly (and even rarely) presented so I can't see how you would unit test something like that.

Comment: I agree. That's why I asked ;)